# Error Build Swift code with GoogleCast

Tags: swift, google-cast

I don't know whats wrong with my GoogleCast API. When i imported GGCast into my project it was OK. Everythin good. but it had problem when i built it.

**My error dialog**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that's an integration issue. From my point of view, the best solution would be to use [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) and to integrate [`google-cast-sdk`](https://cocoapods.org/pods/google-cast-sdk) with it.

If you're not familiar with CocoaPods, please take some time to look at [this introduction](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html).

It will not take you more than an hour to understand how CocoaPods works, and to integrate it. But it will save you lots of time in the future.